# How to set icon for pageaction in firefox android extension

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I use PageActions to create address bar button in adnroid ff addon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/PageActions.jsm.

And I have icon.png in main directory of addon project. Example of my PageAction:

```
PageActions.add({
   icon: "icon.png",
   title: "My page action",
   clickCallback: function () {
   showAlertDlg('myaddon', 'action');
   }
 });
```

But button create without icon. How correctly set icon to my pageaction?

Comment: I don't think you can link to that main icon. Try putting a copy in the your `data` folder and then set `icon: self.data.url('myicon.png')`

Comment: @Noitidart is this work with bootstrap project or only in jpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
-Create in main project folder skin/icon.png
-Create chrome.manifest with content:
content my-addon content/
skin my-addon classic/1.0 skin/
-Use icon as:

```
uuid = PageActions.add({
    icon: "chrome://my-addon/skin/icon.png",
    title: "My page action",
    clickCallback: function () {
    }
});
```

Problem was that I wrote icon: "chrome://skin/icon.png" without addon name "my-addon" in path